# Problem with defining own shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, system-monitor

I'd like to have a shortcut to the system monitor like it's in Windows with CTRL + Shift + Escape. I read through internet and did it like it's written, but it's not working. Does anybody know why it's not working? Did I use wrong keywords?

using the gconf-editor:

1. in **app/metacity/global_keybindings:** setting value in run_command_1 into `<Control><Shift>Escape`
2. in **keybinding_commands:** setting value of command_1 into `gnome-system-monitor`.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question.. but this is what I do- `Ctrl+Alt+F2` to switch to tty2. Log in. Run `htop`. Or just run `htop` in a terminal emulator. Honestly.. the gnome-system-monitor leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It works with me using Keyboard Shortcuts**

1. Open Keyboard Shortcuts.
2. Add a custom Keyboard shortcut with the command `gnome-system-monitor`.

[image]

3.Done

[image]